# Windows still using page file on C:/ despite set to none

Tags: windows-10, pagefile

TLDR: I have set my page file to be exclusively on my secondary E: drive in advanced device settings, however after reboot I still see a lot of page files still being written on my primary C: drive causing thermal issues (and yes those two are physically different drives not just different partitions). How do I fix it?

I have two SSDs on my laptop, one is NVMe M.2 drive (Boot) and another one is SATA. I have 12 GB of RAM (Yes its one of those weird OEM configurations) so completely turning of swap files is not an option. I run VMs and games regularly so it is pretty common to see 20 - 30 GB of page file. However my M.2 drive will get really hot and thermal throttle to the point that it will throttle to 5MB/s read/write (Down from 2GB/s read/write) and the whole system is unusable. Therefore I have set my page file to be exclusively on my SATA drive. This has worked however until recently, the SATA drive is accidentally disconnected. I booted up, saw my drive is disconnected because the connection came loose, shutdown, and reconnected my SATA drive. I reconfigured every page file settings like before, and yet this time Windows is still exclusively using my NVMe drive for page file, despite I set the page file to none in the advanced device settings. How do I fix it?

Comment: Screen shot of the configuration settings may help. Uncheck the allow system or Windows to manager or whatever it is, reboot again, then check.

Comment: Restart is required for pagefile changes to take effect.